# Script or method to move email from a POP Inbox to an IMAP Inbox on a headless server

Tags: email, imap, pop3, transfer, headless

I have cantankerous POP server from a remote legacy system that I can't control or change.

My customers' need to receive all these emails on their internal IMAP server so all the office administrators can all see the emails and also know what's been done with them. (Read, Unread, etc.)

I'd like the Dovecot 2.2.9 (Gentoo AMD64, 13.0, Headless) Server to pick up the emails from the off-site POP3 server and deposit them in the Inbox for an IMAP account on our Dovecot Server.

I had been trying to use a Thunderbird filter to do this, but this predicates that an extra system is running all the time.

I'm looking for input as to how this could be done. I have looked through the Dovecot documentation and haven't found a mechanism that suits this purpose, but I am IN NO WAY conversant in Dovecot administration.

My other concept is to try to use Mutt or another 'powerful' command-line based email client to make the transfer for me.

If anyone's done anything like this before and can just say:

- You configure **widget A** to **procedure 1** into **widget B**

I'll then happily figure out the rest myself.

Comment: Looks like we'll be using fetchmail to dovecot-lda
 `poll foo.bar with proto POP3
  user USER there with pass PASSWORD
  options fetchall
  mda "/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver"`

Comment: That's pretty much done it. I'm just fighting with a few protocol problems. I can get it to run as a daemon, but not as a service (init.d).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, then.  If that's what you want.

You configure [Charles Cazabon's `getmail`](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) to fetch from the POP3 server and write the mail directly into the Dovecot mailbox(es).

### Further reading

- [*POP3Aggregator*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/POP3Aggregator).  Ubuntu Community wiki.
- Juraj (2009-04-19).  [*Fetching of emails from a POP3 server and serving via IMAP (Ubuntu)*](http://jurajsplayground.com/2009/04/19/fetching-of-emails-from-a-pop3-server-and-serving-via-imap-ubuntu/). Juraj's Playground.
- Thibault Jouannic (2013-09-23).  [*Synchronize all your mailboxes on your own private email server*](http://www.miximum.fr/synchronize-all-your-mailboxes-on-your-own-server.html).  Miximum.